# The Yahtzee Game

Tags: java, object-oriented, enum

I am designing two methods to be used in a Java implementation of Yahtzee.

For those not familiar with the game:

> Players take turns rolling dice and acquire points based on the face
>   up values of a roll. 5 6-sided dice are rolled per turn. There are 13
>   categories that determine a score, which are listed
>   [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahtzee#Upper_section).

Here is the gist of each method:

1. `Score(category, roll`) - takes the name of a category (any data type) and an array (in my code, an array of integers), which represents the face up values of a roll. This method computes the score.
2. `SuggestCategory(roll)` - takes an array of integers, which represents the face up values of a roll, and determines the valid Yahtzee categories that will give the maximum score (so this method will probably use the previous method).

Currently, my `category` parameter is an enum type and the `roll` is an array of integers. Here are the implementations of the methods:

```
package yahtzee;

/**
* The YahtzeeUtility class implements the Score(Category, int []) and SuggestedCategory(int []) methods.
* It also contains a private method, ValidateCategoryExists(Category, int []), which validates that a 
* category exists for a given roll.
* 
* @author Robert Blatner
* 
*/
public class YahtzeeUtility {

    /**
     * Validates that a category exists given the values in the roll.
     * 
     * @param category
     *              the name of category as an enum constant
     * @param count
     *              the number of occurrences of values 1 - 6 as an array of integers
     * @return a boolean value corresponding to whether category exists for a given count
     */
    private boolean ValidateCategoryExists(Category category, int [] count){
        assert category != null;
        assert count != null;

        boolean validated = false;


        if( category == Category.THREE_OF_A_KIND){ 

            for(int value : count)
                if(value == 3) validated = true;

        }
        else if( category == Category.FOUR_OF_A_KIND){ // "FourOfAKind"

            for(int value : count)
                if(value == 4) validated = true;

        }
        else if( category == Category.YAHTZEE){ // "AllOfAKind"

            for(int value : count)
                if(value == 5) validated = true;

        }
        else if( category == Category.FULL_HOUSE){ // "FullHouse"

            boolean three = false;
            boolean two = true;

            for(int value : count){
                if(value == 2) two = true;
                else if(value == 3) three = true;
            }

            if (two && three) validated = true;

        }
        else if( category == Category.SMALL_STRAIGHT){ // "Small Straight"
            int seq_cnt = 0;

            for(int value : count){
              if(value > 0){
                  seq_cnt++;
                  if(seq_cnt == 4){
                      validated = true;
                      break;
                  }
              }
              else {
                  seq_cnt = 0;
              } 
            }
        }
        else if( category == Category.LARGE_STRAIGHT){ // "Large Straight"
            int seq_cnt = 0;

            for(int value : count){

              if(value > 0){
                  seq_cnt++;
                  if(seq_cnt == 5){
                      validated = true;
                      break;
                  }
              }
              else {
                  seq_cnt = 0;
              }

            }
        }

        return validated;
    }

    /**
     * Given a category name and an array of values, this method computes a score.
     * 
     * @param category
     *              the name of the category as an enum constant
     * @param roll
     *              an array of integers that represent the face up values of a given roll
     * @return the computed score as an integer
     * @throws NullPointerException
     *              is thrown if either parameter is null
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *              is thrown if value of roll is outside of range 1-6.
     */
    public int Score(Category category, int [] roll) {

        if(roll == null) throw new NullPointerException("Array containing values of roll is null.");
        if(category == null) throw new NullPointerException("Category string parameter is null.");

        // Count face up values (and validate values)
        int [] count = new int[8];
        for(int value : roll){
            if(value < 1 || value > 8) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value of dice is invalid.");

            count[value - 1] += 1;
        }

        // Select Category (and validate category exists if category is not "Aces" -> "Eights" or "Chance") 
        int score = 0;          
        if(category == Category.ACES)
            score = count[0];

        else if(category == Category.TWOS)
            score = count[1]*2;

        else if(category == Category.THREES)
            score = count[2]*3;

        else if(category == Category.FOURS)
            score = count[3]*4;

        else if(category == Category.FIVES) 
            score = count[4]*5;

        else if(category == Category.SIXES) 
            score = count[5]*6;

        else if(category == Category.SEVENS) 
            score = count[6]*7;

        else if(category == Category.EIGHTS) 
            score = count[7]*8;

        else if(category == Category.THREE_OF_A_KIND || category == Category.FOUR_OF_A_KIND) { 
            if(ValidateCategoryExists(category, count)){
                for(int value : roll)
                    score += value;
            }
            else score = 0;
        }
        else if(category == Category.YAHTZEE) { 
            if(ValidateCategoryExists(category, count)) score = 50;
            else score = 0;

        }
        else if(category == Category.FULL_HOUSE) {
            if(ValidateCategoryExists(category, count)) score = 25;
            else score = 0;

        }
        else if(category == Category.SMALL_STRAIGHT){
            if(ValidateCategoryExists(category, count)) score = 30;
            else score = 0;
        }
        else if(category == Category.LARGE_STRAIGHT){
            if(ValidateCategoryExists(category, count)) score = 40;
            else score = 0;
        }
        else if(category == Category.CHANCE) 
            for(int value : roll)
                score += value;     

        return score;
    }

    /**
     * Given an array of values, this method determines the category(s) that return the highest scores. 
     * 
     * @param roll
     *              an array of integers that represent the face up values of a given roll
     * @return a string array that contains names of suggested categories
     * @throws NullPointerException
     *              is thrown if the integer array argument is null
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *              is thrown if a value in the array of integers parameter is not between 1 and 6.
     */
    public String []SuggestedCategories(int [] roll){

        Category []categories = Category.values();
        int num_categories = categories.length;
        int [] scores = new int[num_categories];

        // Compute Scores for every category
        for(int i = 0; i < num_categories; i++)
            scores[i] = Score(categories[i], roll);

        // Determine max scores
        int count = 0;
        int max = 0;
        for(int score : scores){

            if(score > max) {
                max = score;
                count = 1;
            }
            else if(score == max){
                count++;
            }
        }

        // Consolidate max scores in to a String []
        String [] result = new String[count];
        int result_i = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < num_categories; i++)
            if( scores[i] == max){
                result[result_i] = categories[i].toString();            
                result_i++;
            }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Here is the enum implementation for the *category* parameter:

```
package yahtzee;

/**
 * Category is an enum class that contains the possible dice game category values. An enum allows 
 * errors to be caught at compile time if a client misspells a category name. The downside is that 
 * an entry will need to be added if a category is added to the game.
 * 
 * @author Robert
 *
 */
public enum Category {
    ACES("Aces"),
    TWOS("Twos"),
    THREES("Threes"),
    FOURS("Fours"),
    FIVES("Fives"),
    SIXES("Sixes"),
    THREE_OF_A_KIND("ThreeOfAKind"),
    FOUR_OF_A_KIND("FourOfAKind"),
    YAHTZEE("Yahtzee"),
    FULL_HOUSE("FullHouse"),
    SMALL_STRAIGHT("SmallStraight"),
    LARGE_STRAIGHT("LargeStraight"),
    CHANCE("Chance");

    private final String name;

    Category(String name){
        this.name = name;       
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

The two methods run without errors. The score method does this:

1. Counts face up values
2. Validates a category exists
3. Computes the value of the score

Maybe I could separate `Score()` into 3 private methods. Does anyone have suggestions for making the code more readable/organized?

Otherwise, is my variable/method naming okay? Is this a good use case for an enum?

**Update:**

Yes, I am using Java 8.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some helpful answers.

Comment: It's not really `ACE` in dice, it's just one...

Comment: The category for summing ones in Yahtzee is called "Aces".

Comment: Are you on Java 8?

Comment: @RobertBlatner see my updated answer (I missed your update on Java 8 usage previously)... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Style

- `ValidateCategoryExists(Category, int[])`
- `Score(Category, int[])`
- `SuggestedCategories(int[])`

These can be better renamed as `validateCategoryExists`/`getScore`/`getSuggestedCategories`, to follow Java's standard method naming convention.

Arrays are typically declared as `T[]`, and you have some slight inconsistencies there. Standardizing to `T[]` should ease readability as well. Also, on the topic of inconsistency, I will also suggest sticking with the use of curly braces `{ ... }` throughout as missing out just one of them may be ripe for a huge mistake/losing an hour of sleep while debugging.

## `validateCategoryExists`

Since this is just one large `if-else-if` 'ladder', you can consider using a `switch`, which the `Category` `enum` will work nicely with. Do also consider `return`-ing early.

Since on Java 8, you can even streamline the process *slightly* by using [`IntStream`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) for the simpler comparisons...

```
private static boolean hasNumber(int[] array, int value) {
    return Arrays.stream(count).anyMatch(i -> i == value);
}
```

The logic for `SMALL_STRAIGHT`/`LARGE_STRAIGHT` can also probably be put into a method as well, since the only variable is the number of sequential non-zero counts.

## `getScore`

Similar to the above section, consider if you want to replace with a `switch` and/or early `return` usage.

For the `else-if` blocks that require calling `validateCategoryExists(Category, int[])`, you can rewrite them as such:

```
} else if(category == Category.YAHTZEE) {
    // return early
    return validateCategoryExists(category, count) ? 50 : 0;
    // or
    // score = validateCategoryExists(category, count) ? 50 : 0;
} else if(category == Category.FULL_HOUSE) {
    // ...
} // ...
```

## `getSuggestedCategories`

The general idea is to:

1. Create a `Map` of `Category` to the score (hint: an [`EnumMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) will be quite useful here).
2. Find the largest score from the `Map`'s values.
3. Loop through the `Map` again to put the required keys into a `List<String>`, and then the desired `String[]` return object can be derived by using [`toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-):

   ```
   return list.toArray(new String[0]);
   ```

There is an alternative implementation if you are on Java 8. Instead of keying on your `Category` `enum`, you can use a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) to key by the *scores* after [`groupingBy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) the `enum` values. Getting your result is then just one more call to [`TreeMap.lastEntry()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#lastEntry--):

```
TreeMap<Integer, List<Category>> treeMap = 
        EnumSet.allOf(Category.class).stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> getScore(c, roll), 
                            TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
return treeMap.lastEntry().getValue().toArray(new String[0]);
```